# Can I pass arguments to a ClearCase trigger?

Tags: perl, version-control, clearcase

Checking code in at my shop involves a complicated dance, ending with answering a couple of prompts from inside a trigger on the ClearCase checkin.

I'd like to modify the trigger to take command line arguments. Is this possible?

Failing that, I'd like to be able to jigger STDIN such that the prompts get answered.  I've tried using a HERE file, but the second prompt is repeated ad infinitum.  I'm writing my script in perl.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited my answer to address your edit about STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

The modification, of the trgger requires using [`cleartool mktrtype`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm)

You have access to environment variables, and arguments depending on the type of object your trgger applies to.

But you wouldn't have access to any command-line argument though.

---

> Failing that, I'd like to be able to jigger STDIN such that the prompts get answered

Check out [`clearprompt`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearprompt.htm):

> The `clearprompt` command prompts the user for input, then either stores the input in a file or returns an appropriate exit status.
>   **`clearprompt` is designed for use in trigger action and GUI scripts**.
>
> On UNIX and Linux systems, `clearprompt` can interact with the user either through `stdin` and `stderr` (CLI mode), or through a pop-up window (GUI mode).

For instance:

> Create an all-element trigger type that **prompts for the source of an algorithm when an element of type `c_source` is created**.
>   Firing the trigger executes a script named `hlink_algorithm`, which invokes the `clearprompt` utility to obtain the necessary information.
>   The script then creates a text-only hyperlink between the newly created element object (for example, `foo.c@@`) and the specified text.
>   The `hlink_algorithm` script is shown immediately after the `mktrtype` command.

```
cmd-context mktrtype -element -all -nc -postop mkelem -eltype c_source \
-exec /net/neon/scripts/hlink_algorithm describe_algorithm
Created trigger type "describe_algorithm".
```

> `hlink_algorithm` script:

```
clearprompt text -outfile /usr/tmp/alg.$CLEARCASE_PPID \
-multi_line  
-def "Internal Design" -prompt "Algorithm Source Document:" 

TOTEXT=‘cat /usr/tmp/alg.$CLEARCASE_PPID‘
cleartool mkhlink -ttext "$TOTEXT" design_spec 
 $CLEARCASE_PN$CLEARCASE_XN_SFX 

rm /usr/tmp/alg.$CLEARCASE_PPID
```

Comment: It's already using clearprompt (or so I assume, since it's prompting inside the trigger).  That's exactly what I don't want.  I want to provide the **input** programmatically, so that I can batch the job.

Comment: @user72751 The you need to modify your trigger script in order for it to *not* use `clearprompt`, and to compute the right answer. You can define an environment variable which, if define, would make your script not call `clearprompt`, and if not define, do what it does right now.